# Fingerprint scanner not recognized

Tags: command-line, drivers, windows, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I am using a Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ITL05 with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dualbooted into it. It seems like it didn't recognize my fingerprint scanner. I typed `lsusb` in the terminal and this is what it did.

```
****@ideapad-3-13itl05-ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:5415 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 258a:0049 BY Tech Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

****@ideapad-3-13itl05-ubuntu:~$
```

---

Any ways to make my laptop recognize the fingerprint scanner?
"`Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint`
"

(NOT RELATED TO QUESTION: Ingore my chinese gaming devices, i ordered a new mouse.)
(The **** in "****@ideapad-3-13itl05-ubuntu:~$ " is just a censor of my real name)

[image: Settings app not recognizing my fingerprint sensor]

By the way my Lenovo isn't Ubuntu-certified. The fingerprint sensor detects in `lsusb` but Settings will not detect it. There is no option for the fingerprint.

Comment: So why are you saying it isn't recognized? You are showing the output of a command that correctly lists it, so are you sure there is a problem? Have you tried using it? How? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead? Please [edit] your question and add the answers and any other details.

Comment: Settings, it won't recognize my fingerprint sensor.

Comment: I did also press the unlock at the top of the window, fingerprint login won't appear.

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and clarify where the problem is. What exactly is that screenshot from? Which part of which settings? And what were you expecting to see? Are you saying you want to find a GUI way to enable the fingerprint scanner?

Comment: Detecting some hardware is one thing and is possible even if no supported driver is installed … But using it requires the presence and correct configuration of a supported driver for that piece of hardware which seems to be missing on your system … Unless you install a compatible driver, that fingerprint hardware can’t be used … Find the right driver if it exists and install it first.